# Zero distance to a closed set implies membership in it

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

What is the easiest/meaningful way to infere

$ A \mbox{ closed}, d(x,A)=0 \Rightarrow x\in A $

Proof.
Assume oppostie: $x\in X\setminus A$.

It is easy to see that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subseteq X\setminus A$ which is open.

...?

QED

Comment: If $x \notin A$, show that $d(x,A)>0$.

Comment: "It is easy to see that there exists ε>0 such that Bε(x)⊆X∖A"  No, it is easy to see that is not in the least bit true.  $d(x,A)$ means that every $B_\epsilon(x)$ will contain points of $A$ so that is not in the least bit true.

Comment: Prove that the definition of $d(x,A)=0$ implies $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $d(x,A)=0$ then there is a sequence of points ${x_n}$ in $A$ so that $d(x, x_n) \rightarrow 0$.  So ${x_n}$ converges to $x$.  Since A is closed we have that $x$ is in $A$.

Comment: Why such sequence exists? (I imagine using axiom of choice on something like epsilon=1/n "borders" from the inside of A, but how to write it precisely?).

Comment: It follows from the definition of infimum of a set of real numbers.  The infimum is zero so there is a sequence of real numbers in the set of values $\{d(x,y) | y \in A\}$ that goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

By definition , $d(x,A)=inf\{d(x,y)\backslash y\in A\}$,So $d(x,A)=0 \implies \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists x_{n},d(x,x_{n})<\frac{1}{n}$,in particular $x$ is the limit of a sequence of elements of $A$, since $A$ is closed,$x\in A$.
your approach also works,let y be an element of $X\setminus A$,since $X\setminus A$ is open ,there must exist some $\epsilon$ such that $B(y,\epsilon)\subset X\setminus A $ ,this proves that $d(y,A)\geq \epsilon >0$

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in A$ then $d(x,A)=0$ because $x\in A$ and $d(x,x) = 0$.

But if $x\not \in A$ but $d(x,A)= 0$ then that means for every $y \in A$ that $d(x,y) > 0$ *but* the $\inf\{d(x,y)|y\in A\} = 0$.  That means that every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $y\in A$ so that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$.

But that means:  For every $\epsilon > 0$ that $N_\epsilon(x) = \{w|d(x,w) < \epsilon\}$ will contain a point $y \in A$.  As $x \not \in A$ that means $x\ne y$.

And that is the very definition of a limit point!

So we have proven

> If $d(x,A) = 0$ then either $x \in A$; or $x$ is a limit point of $A$; or both.

So.....

If $A$ is closed than it contains all its limit points (that's the definition).

So if $d(x,A) =0$ either $x \in A$ and we are done; or $x$ is a limit point of $A$ and therefore $x\in A$ and we are done.